# angularjs post data to mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, post

I have simple code using angularjs,

```
 $http.post(postToCreateURL, addingProducts, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
        .success(function () {
        })
        .error(function () {
        });
```

And I want bind this data to this Mvc controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(ProductModel model)
    {
        NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

        var products = db.Products.Select(s => new ProductModel
        {
            ProductName = s.ProductName,
            SupplierID = s.SupplierID,
            CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
            QuantityPerUnit = s.QuantityPerUnit,
            UnitPrice = s.UnitPrice,
            UnitsInStock = s.UnitsInStock,
            UnitsOnOrder = s.UnitsOnOrder,
            ReorderLevel = s.ReorderLevel,
            Discontinued = s.Discontinued

        }).Take(5).ToList();

        return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In this situation I'm getting null values. Thanks in advance!

Comment: headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} ?

Comment: if I did't use this it has returned error while sending request and couldn't send

Comment: If you use application/json?

Comment: can you please tell how you are consuming json data send by angularjs controller in your mvc controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     var request = {
        ProductName: 'aa',
        SupplierID: 'aa',
        CategoryID: 'aa',

        ...

        Discontinued: 'zzz'
    } 




    $http.post(" URL IN HERE ", JSON.stringify(request), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
```